# Jenkins: automatic tool installers missing JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

Normally, in ${JENKINS_HOME}/updates/ there are several JSON files for automatically installing various tools. Namely, the one I need is hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller . Two others are suddenly missing: for Ant, and for JDK.

End result is, my build fails because it can't install Maven from Apache automatically (as [detailed here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s06.html)).

I am deploying Jenkins to AWS. What's strange is, I have an AMI (image) that previously was working fine, that suddenly is encountering this problem. I've banged my head on this one extensively with no solution.

Looks like you can find the JSON that I'm failing to download here:
http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/updates/current/updates/

Except the JSON there is prepended with "downloadService.post()", indicating that hudson.model.DownloadService is probably doing something (other hints point to that, as well).

Any ideas?

EDIT: Actually, it looks like the last AMI that worked does, in fact, still work.

Should mention: The project is, creating a Jenkins AMI via Chef and Packer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this about a week after posing. Turns out, the issue was on Jenkins update center side of things, suddenly changing to a smaller RSA Key:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31089

At the time, the workaround was this:

```
sed -i s/'jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024'/'jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 512'/ /usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

Which allowed Java to grab the updates, even though the update center was using a smaller RSA key.